# How to fill 10% of the Android screen?

Tags: android

How can I fill the screen with 2 horizontal colors, such that the down one will get 10% of the screen? (like a toolbar)?

I'm trying modify the [Linear Layout example](http://file:///home/wellington/Android/android-sdk-linux_86/docs/resources/tutorials/views/hello-linearlayout.html) to:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

  <LinearLayout
      android:orientation="horizontal"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent"
      android:layout_weight="1">
      <TextView
          android:text="green"
          android:gravity="center_horizontal"
          android:background="#00aa00"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"
          android:layout_weight="1"/>
      <TextView
          android:text="blue"
          android:gravity="center_horizontal"
          android:background="#0000aa"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"
          android:layout_weight="1"/>
  </LinearLayout>

  <LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1">
    <TextView
        android:text="single row"
        android:textSize="15pt"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
  </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

but if change the

```
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
```

for

```
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

on the down "panel"(is it a panel?) the text is not shown complete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will want to use fill_parent and not wrap content, and what should work is if the upper part has a weight of 9 and the lower part a weight of 1. The weight should work as a percentage of the total weights, so 9+1 = 10 and 1/10 is 10%.